# Transfer money between users?

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there a way with Drupal to transfer money between users? Im making a skill sharing website, so users can buy and sell their skills. Thanks

Comment: No, you need to make use of 3rd party payment gateways like PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Ubercart funds](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart_funds) module that is the best answer for your question; the module still has a development snapshot only, though.

This will make you able to transfer funds through your drupal sites to different users.

> Ubercart Funds implements a Site Funds Management System using Ubercart, It integrates features like Deposit Funds, Withdraw Funds, Transfer Funds..etc, which makes implementing most features of a Money site like Paypal or Skrill possible and easy using Drupal.

Comment: As I understand that would allow users to buy points and then exchange points, but I still need to allow users to 'cash out' and exchange those points for real money. Does this have to be done manually? Thanks

Comment: There is a Commerce Userpoints module that allows buy stuff with points or buy points (patch in the issue queue), but getting cash out again is not something that is currently available for Userpoints as far as I'm aware of. I actually don't know of a module that would allow something like this in general, not sure how this would work. PayPal e.g. seems to have some sort of API for this, so users would have to provide their paypal account, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191887/how-to-send-money-to-paypal-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Was just looking into this myself and came across [Commerce Funds](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_funds).

> Commerce Funds implements a Site Funds Management System using Drupal Commerce, It integrates features like Deposit Funds, Withdraw Funds, Transfer Funds..etc, which makes implementing most features of a Money site like Paypal or Skrill possible and easy using Drupal.