# How to pay users programmatically (payment from site to users)

Tags: rules, commerce

Is there a way to reward registered users with real money in a programmatic way, i.e. via Rules?

Like Commerce Card On File but in reverse:

1. My site (or some admin account) has a credit card (or whatever works) saved for later billing.
2. One of my users has saved an account to receive payments (a credit
   card, a paypal account or whatever works in Europe).
3. The user does something that earns him a reward.
4. He (or a scheduled component) fires a Rule that create an order and
   pays from the admin card to his account automatically.

*The legal aspects are not relevant at this stage (valid billing for taxes, which would be **from** the user, etc.)*

**UPDATE**: I found [Commerce Funds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_funds) and **Stripe Connect** together with Commerce Stripe module to be promising, still I don't see the functionality right away.

Anyone having experience with creating a real market (real money) on Drupal?

I also submitted a feature request (https://www.drupal.org/node/2398423) on Commerce Stripe module.

**UPDATE 2**: **Paypal** has something here https:// www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside. It is called **MassPay** but is limited to max 250 recipients via the API and 5000 via a static csv list.
I don't have info on Drupal modules implementing that, if you do, please share.

In the meantime, I could still create a View, data-export it to CSV and manually upload to Paypal to make the payments each month to my users, 5k at a time. It's not so bad, but a completely integrated and automated solution would be way better.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this. All 'money' remains in the site, but can be withdrawn. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/36695/9921

Comment: Do you have any hints on how money can be withdrawn by the user (i.e. without further human action from the paying card holder)? That is the crucial point in the question!

Comment: The modules come with an API and a withdraw function. With some custom coding you should be able to do something.